# Current employer won't accept my resignation, and knows where my new company is?

Tags: india, relieving-letter

Currently I am working in small IT company in India, where I've been for the last 4 and a half months. Now I have been offered a job in MNC with a good salary package.

My problem is my boss knows where I am going to move to, and he is not accepting my resignation. He threatens me, saying he'll mail MNC and cancel my placement if I haven't complete my pending work.

Please help me. What can I do?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I doubt that it is legal for someone to blackmail you like this, but it depends on the laws in your country and your contract.

You need to go to a lawyer to get the correct advice in this case - that kind of behaviour is entirely unacceptable.

As an aside, the boss is a fool, if he thinks you will produce good quality work whilst being blackmailed to stay.

Comment: Thanks yochannah...
I am from India.Can you give me confirmation that such kind of blackmailing is legal in my country.

Comment: @abhi Nope. Unfortunately we can't provide legal advice on The Workplace - hence why I suggested speaking to a lawyer.

Comment: Hey yochannah,
Can I talk to my HR about this matter..

Comment: I don't see why not, but things might be different in India compared to where I live (the UK) so be cautious

Comment: I would strongly suggest talking to a neutral third party about this. The HR at your current company will want to say anything to keep you there - so they may not tell you all of your rights. I would give that same advice to anyone, in any country (including the US, where I live.)