# Can a company increase notice period for any reason, while serving?

Tags: new-job, job-change, india, notice-period

**P.S -** Please note that the question mentioned in [this link](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/66613/employer-not-accepting-my-resignation-and-threatens-me-by-not-giving-relieving-l) is not similar to my situation, as my situation is better than that, and I don't want to go for the lawyer thing before trying other means. I want people to help me with those alternate means. Law is the last option that I want to use.

I am in a startup, currently serving notice period. There were some internal politics, due to which my task was to handle the client, while another employee would do all the coding related work (as approved by the company officially). The official notice period is of 3 months. And it is mentioned that, notice period may be extended if I take any kind of leave during this time **(which I haven't)** .

After completion of 2 months of my notice, I asked my manager to introduce my replacement to the client. Stating that I am leaving may hinder the progress of the Client's work, in which case, the company may not release me immediately on my last working day.  The manager agreed  to introduce my replacement.

Now, the client wants to conduct a formal interview of my replacement (client interviews everyone before they can work on its project, including mine when I started). Now, my replacement is threatening that if he is **not** selected, **then I will not be released.**
The problem is, I have already been selected in a reputed company ,and have given my joining date to them.

So, my question is - Is this legal? Can a company not release an employee even when the employee has not broken any rule, (which would otherwise increase the notice period) ? What can I do in case they sort to such unethical behaviour?

P.S - Relieving letter is mandatory in case one wants to join a new company. And that letter is given to employees on the last working day.

Comment: Isn't this question more suitable for something like law.stackexchange.com? If the question was more about how to handle the situation you're in I can see it fitting here, but since the question only seems to inquire about the strict legality of what's going on it might be out of place.


And my god the whole relieving letter thing is so crazy. Every time I read a question relating to it I have to stop myself from laughing and going "silly you, you're obviously not a slave" and then it turns out the employer actually almost holds that amount of power...

Comment: @Tony I want to know how to handle this. I mean if I use law and order (or even involve a lawyer) then it will be a whole new thing.

Comment: Both the title and how the "So my question is [....]" part is phrased highlights the legal part though. And I think that's the most important part too actually, figuring out your legal position is going to impact how you can go forwards with it quite drastically. If it's only about potential solutions: Perhaps there's an option for a relieving letter with a later date? Give them a month extra but at least it's set in stone? Alternatively I read a somewhat related question on here that had the company not demand the relieving letter, which I'm not sure about the legality of either...

Comment: @Tony Legal solution is an option, but I would not go that far without trying other things (unless not feasible)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Employer not accepting my resignation and Threatens me by Not giving Relieving Letter](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/66613/employer-not-accepting-my-resignation-and-threatens-me-by-not-giving-relieving-l)

Comment: I think @DaveGremlin is right. Your problem is the relieving letter.

Comment: Who is the replacement threatening? Your bosses?  He doesn't control whether they do or don't give you your release letter.  You? He doesn't determine whether release is given and you don't determine who gets hired.  Can you clarify?

Comment: Replacement is threatening me; that I wont be released if he isnt selected

Comment: @Nobody Umm, no. The company hasn't denied the relieving letter as of now.

Comment: Your concern is the relieving letter required by the new company. The old client's selection is not your business unless the replacement has the power to stop you getting the letter. This means the replacement has the control over your current employer. Is this the case? If not, why do you care about the old client's selection?

Comment: If the old client insists that you continue to work for them, never accept **any**  replacement, do you stay there? This is why your problem is the letter, not that particular replacement.

Comment: Does your boss agree with the replacement's threat -- that if he doesn't past muster, your release letter is delayed?

Comment: @DanielR.Collins Boss does not. But, if I go ask him, he will agree, probably to threaten me. Not sure

Answer (score 3):

It is NOT legal for them to withhold their relieving letter IF both parties have fulfilled their part of the contract (I have no reference directly to indian law here, but similar cases across the internet are all about fine-combing contracts to see if they've actually been fulfilled and usually are about what happens if the notice period isn't fulfilled. If you've lived up to your end of the contract, the contract holds and you have a right to your relieving letter).

As far as I can tell you have 3 options:

1. Have your boss change his mind.
   I'm sure this option looks silly here, but obviously the first step would simply be to talk to your boss again. Apparently the legal situation is very clear - if you've lived up to your obligations in the contract they cannot withhold the letter from you and it might have legal consquences for them down the line if you choose to go down that path. Simply being aware that this is an option for you might give you enough leverage for them to change their minds. You said you don't want to go down this path which I understand 110%, but if you have to...
2. Consult a lawyer.
   As long as you fulfill your contractual obligations, you're entitled to a relieving letter. I have no clue how your contract looks and exactly what is expected of you there, but if it's only 3 months minus abscence there should not be a legal basis to withhold it from you. I'm pretty sure this would end quickly, as your employer has 0 interest in starting a legal battle that they cannot win. Most likely being aware of your legal situation is going to be enough during a confrontation, but maybe you'll need a stern letter written by a lawyer with the appropriate legalese. Further down the line you can have an actual legal battle and claim damages for your lost time, but I did not read enough into those cases to know how that would turn out, it was only referenced as technically being an option.
3. Talk to your future employer.
   As I mentioned in the comment I remember someone on this stackexchange getting their new job without a relieving letter, and posts like https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/things-do-when-current-employer-giving-youdelaying-c-khubchandani/ seem to indicate that there's an option to go forward without the relieving letter.

> ~If you have completed the notice period and have to join new employer on immediate basis and you still aren't relieved from present employer , you may address this issue to the new employer and just send them a resignations acceptance copy .

If your new company is more decent and somewhat aware of your situation, who knows, maybe you can just ghost your current employer unless you see a future where that specific relieving letter will be necessary.

What a ride these relieving letters are!

(I also saw a bunch of seemingly relevant questions / answers from a site called kaanoon, but apparently that site likes to nickle and dime customers by giving "half truths" so that the person asking has to pay to ask for clarification, so I omitted those links. Still fairly certain they're not lying about anything though, so the legal situation seems pretty solid despite the lack of references in this post)

Answer (score 3):

To be honest, it just sounds like your replacement is trying to bully you into helping them get hired. It's unclear to me how much power they actually have.

My interpretation of Indian workplace culture, and I apologize if this is offensive or blatantly not true, that is is more cutthroat than a lot of other cultures.

I don't exactly understand the power dynamic at play here, but you should try to confirm with your boss, perhaps indirectly if you need, if they intend to attempt increase your notice period.

My understanding is that you don't always need a relieving letter. It can be more complicated, but some other proof that the employment has ended can sometimes be used.